# how to close navbar after going to another page in react.js and daisy ui

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, tailwind-ui, daisyui

I create nav bar with react, tailwind and Daisy. UI and react_router_dom and when it goes to another page it's still open, and I want it to close after it goes to another page.

```
 <div class="drawer">
  <input id="my-drawer-3" type="checkbox" class="drawer-toggle" /> 
  <div class="drawer-content flex flex-col">
    <div class="w-full navbar bg-base-100">
         <img src={Logo} className=' ml-3 w-40 justify-end mr-auto' alt="" />
      <div class="flex-none lg:hidden">
        <label for="my-drawer-3" class="">
        <HiMenuAlt3  className='btn btn-square btn-ghost w-'/>
        </label>
      </div> 
      <div class="flex-none hidden lg:block font-semiBold">
        <ul class="menu menu-horizontal">
        <Link to='/' id='a' className='mr-20 a'>Games</Link>
        <Link to='/about-us' id='a' className='mr-20 a'>Hardware</Link>
        <Link to='' id='a' className='mr-20 a'>Services</Link>
        <Link to='' id='a' className='mr-20 a'>News</Link>
        <img src={ShoppingBag} className='w-6 -ml-6 mr-5 cursor-pointer'  alt="shopping-bag" />
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
   
  children
```

Comment: you can use `useEffect` to watch routes

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code on each link.

```
onclick={() => { document.getElementById("my-drawer-3").click(); }}
```

Example:

```
<Link to='/' onclick={() => { document.getElementById("my-drawer-3").click(); }} id='a' className='mr-20 a'>Games</Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I want the drawer menu to close in certain situations too.

I use React's `useRef`, and the following works well.

Add this to the function:

```
const drawerRef = useRef();
function handleMenuClick() {
    if(typeof drawerRef.current === 'undefined') return;
    drawerRef.current.click();
  };
```

Add the ref to the toggle:

```
<input id="my-drawer-3" type="checkbox" class="drawer-toggle" ref={drawerRef}/>
```

Add this to the menu links:

```
onClick={handleMenuClick}
```